# Azure DevOps install .Net Core 3.1 on CI Agents

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to update my agents on an Azure DevOps build pipeline and I need to update to Azure 3.1.

I've found instructions (though vague) to do so using YAML, but I am using the classic view and do not have access (that I know of) to YAML instruction sets.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

I know I need to include a Task before the Restore portion, but there is not step that I see that will allow me to install the SDK on the agents.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Use .NET Core](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7I7h.png) task and specify there the version you need (`3.1.x` for 3.1):

[image]

The task results:

[image]

Comment: This is odd because I don't see this option.  No Package to Install selection

Comment: This is not the .net core regular task, it's *use* .net core task. can you share a screenshot of your pipeline?

Comment: That was the magic sauce.  I only saw the regular .NET Core tasks.  I found the Use .NET ore tasks and was able to get it.  Thank you so much for your help!